# Wordpress: Cache specific SQL queries which run over and over again

Tags: mysql, wordpress, caching

I'm running a quite dynamic Wordpress page with PMPro, WPML and Buddypress - I'm coming to the point where I want to decrease load on the serverside as the MariaDB server has quite some load.

Using Query Monitor, I see that a lot of querys run over and over again on every page load. I know for sure, these do not yield different results, as they depend on admin-options which I never change.

I tried Litespeed Cache and W3TotalCache - these are great plugins and using database and object caching, a lot of queries seem to be cached perfectly - at least I do not see them anymore in Query Monitor.

The question is:
Do you know of any way to cache specific sql queries statically? In W3TC and Litespeed, there is not such thing as a configurable "include"-list for SQL statements - I even thought of patching wpdb myself and cache specific SQL queries by using the md5 of the query as a key for a simple hash=>value dictionary which I store as persistent json file...

These are some example queries which run over and over again:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_fields
WHERE parent_id = 105
AND group_id = 1
ORDER BY option_order ASC

OR

SELECT option_value
FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'
LIMIT 1

OR

SELECT *
FROM wp_pmpro_membership_levels
```

Any many more...

Thanks so much